# When the boss is a way?

Tags: meaning, disambiguities

I came across a picture that was meant to be funny, but puzzled me instead:

http://www.searchquotes.com/sof/images/picture_quotes/31525_20131204_091308_christmas07.jpg

"When the boss is a way work becomes a holiday"
I was expecting *away* in one word.
Is this a pun (that I am missing) or obvious typo?

Comment: Just one more example of why you shouldn't get spelling and grammar tips from the unwashed Internet.

Comment: Hence the stackexchange filtering

Comment: My point is, you didn't get that picture here.

Comment: If it's the Christmas card of a road work company, it might be a pun. "When the boss is a road...", and so forth. Or it might be the Christmas card in a consulting firm providing solutions.. "When the boss is a solution..."

Comment: It is a semi-literate transcription of a (non-English) proverb. Here it is shown correctly http://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1339224280027_1369943.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see it as a pun. The boss being *a way* might imply that the boss, rather than saying no to goofing off at work, is easy to convince and thus becomes *a way* of legitimizing, shall we say, a work slow down.

That said, this is just a guess and my first intuition is that it's incorrect usage or a typo.

Comment: I doubt it's a pun.  Looks like a simple mistake.